# Python split array into intersecting subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to split an array into equally long intersecting subarrays (last element of previous array coincides with first element of the next array and with periodic boundary conditions).

E.g.

```
myarray = np.arange(18)
```

output:

```
splitarray = [[0,1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7,8],[8,9,10,11,12],[12,13,14,15,16],[16,17,0,1,2]]
```

(the 3 last elements of the last subarray correspond to the first 3 elements of the initial array!)

What is the most efficient way to implement this in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use skimage's [`view_as_windows`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) to take overlapping views of the input array, and concatenate the first `w-1` items accordingly for the last window:

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows

def view_strided_with_roll(a, w):
    a = np.r_[a, a[:w-1]]
    return view_as_windows(a, window_shape=w, step=w-1)
```

---

```
myarray = np.arange(18) 
view_strided_with_roll(myarray, 5)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [16, 17,  0,  1,  2]])
```

Comment: if you only want to use numpy:


`np.array([np.roll(myarray, len(myarray) - i)[:5] for i in range(0,len(myarray),4)])`

Comment: No vectorized though, won't scale too well for larger arrays @MBeale

Comment: @MBeale. I've posted the proper numpy solution

Answer (score 3):

The pure-numpy equivalent of [`ski.util.view_as_windows`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) is [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
arr = np.arange(18)
w = 5

if arr.size == 1:
    h = 1
    x = 4
else:
    h = np.ceil((arr.size - 1) / (w - 1)).astype(int)
    x = (1 - arr.size) % (w - 1)

view = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(np.r_[arr, arr[:x]], shape=(h, w), strides=((w - 1) * arr.strides[0], arr.strides[0]))
```

The result is:

```
>>> view
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [16, 17,  0,  1,  2]])
```

The overlapping elements are actually referring to the same memory, so use this view very very carefully.